# flutter error Unable to find git in your PATH in android studio

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

[image: 1]

Hello..
An Unable to find git in your PATH error occurred while configuring flutter in android studio.
I also installed git.
System Variables > Preferences were also set as below.
But I don't know why it can't find git .

git version is 2.40.0.windows.1

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move your flutter sdk directory c: to e:
Then everything works fine

Comment: It was solved by changing the flutter sdk directory.  thanks a lot...